# Does this use the Factory design pattern? (java)

Tags: java, polymorphism, factory-pattern

I'm writing a small program in Java for an assignment in a OOAD class and I have a problem understanding exactly what constitutes a proper factory design pattern and how to implement it in my program.

It's a small program for payroll calculation. There is a base class called Employee and three derived (sub) classes called Hourly, Commissioned and Salaried. They each have different types of data types for payments. I'm only allowed to instantiate one object in the main class, and in the whole program. Through Polymorphism the objects should be shared between classes and I am to write a Factory method to create the objects to be assigned to THE Object.

I have the base class:

```
public class Employee {

protected Employee empFactory(int empType){
    if (empType == 1)
        return new Hourly();
    if (empType == 2)
        return new Commissioned();
    if (empType == 3)
        return new Salaried();
    else
        return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
}
```

And three derived classes:

```
public class Commissioned extends Employee
public class Hourly extends Employee
public class Salaried extends Employee
```

I've left out some of the datatypes and other details, I think this should be enough info. Is the factory method I have a "real" one? I've been reading about abstract and concrete factory methods and concrete products etc, but I'm still confused, don't know how to implement it. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You've almost got a factory *method* there, but not quite. The problem is that the `empFactory` is not static, which means that to make an Employee with it right now requires an existing Employee. Change it to static, and you've taken the first step into the Factory pattern.

The next step is to delegate the logic of the `empFactory` method to a separate class, a factory class. That enables a great deal more complexity (without exposing it to the caller) and is the whole core of the Factory pattern.

Comment: The core of creating factories is creating more complexity? (Sorry, couldn't resist)

Comment: So I'll make a Factory class with the factory method inside. But do I then need another "concrete product" class for each of the employee types, how does that work?

Comment: The core of creating factories is _allowing_ more complexity, and wrapping it up in a neat interface.

Comment: @Donal Fellows If I  have a factory base class with a factory method inside, do I also need a derived "concrete factories" for every type of employee. That's how it looks like on some of the pages I've been reading. 
http://sourcemaking.com/files/sm/images/patterns/Factory_Method__.gif

Comment: @Snorkelfarsan No, you don't. What actually tends to happen is that shortly after you understand what the Factory pattern does, you take a look at the Spring library. Spring is basically a standardization of the Factory pattern which covers almost all of what you need in real code. (Some _really complex_ cases require small factory methods too, but only to encapsulate the most tricky decisions.)

Comment: Note that it's often the case that factory methods take a decision about what class to make based on more info than just the arguments to the method (e.g., a configuration file, system properties).

Comment: @DonalFellows So I should take a look at this spring library?

Comment: @Snorkelfarsan: For the purposes of learning about factories for your class? No. For the purpose of doing this stuff in real deployments? Yes!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know generics you can do a much better factory method that allows you to construct any object of a subclass of Employee.

```
public static <T extends Employee> T empFactory(Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

And a quick example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee emp = Employee.empFactory(Hourly.class);

    System.out.println("The salary is " + emp.getSalary());
}
```

This allows you to instantiate any Employee derived class without having to change the factory method every time you add a new derived class. It also frees you from the ugly (int, derived class) association because you can instantiate an object by simply specifying the derived class you want.

You can also cast the instance if you need to access class specific methods:

```
Hourly hh = (Hourly) emp;

System.out.println("Salary is " + hh.getSalaryH());
```

Note: My Employee class has a getSalary() method and my Hourly class has a getSalaryH() method.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to use generics, but it's not part of the assignment. Don't know if the teacher would approve of it (not that it's a bad solution, but he seemed to have a very specific solution in mind).

Answer (score 0):

Please find below example which describe factory pattern.

```
interface vehicle {
    void start();
    void stop();
}
class car implements vehicle {
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Start car");
    }
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Stop car");
    }
}
class bike implements vehicle {
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Start bike");
    }
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Stop bike");
    }
}
class factory {
    public static vehicle getVehicle(int ch) { //(?)sould be interface type
        vehicle v = null;//local always inialize otherwise error
        //car c = new car();
        //bike b = new bike();
        if(ch == 1) {
            v = new car();
        } else {
            v = new bike();
        }
        return v;
    }
}
class factorymain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        vehicle v;
        v = factory.getVehicle(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        v.start();
        v.stop();
    }
}
```